# Usage of epics with typesafe-actions and Connected React Router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rxjs, redux-observable, typesafe-actions

I am currently setting up an epic that listens to the action of type `LOCATION_CHANGE` or `LocationChangeAction`, which is an action that is triggered whenever the router history changes due to router actions such as `push` or `replace`.

```
import { LOCATION_CHANGE, LocationChangeAction } from 'connected-react-router';
import { isActionOf } from 'typesafe-actions';

const locationEpic: Epic = (action$) => action$.pipe(
  filter(isActionOf(LocationChangeAction)),
  tap((action) => {
    // do the rest here

  })
);
```

However, doing the above will throw the error, and adding `typeof` does not seem to help either.

```
'LocationChangeAction' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

May I know what is the proper way of doing it, by using `typesafe-actions`
's `isActionOf()` operator?

Comment: Can you please add your action definition in the question?

Comment: I think you have to use `onLocationChanged` instead of `LocationChangeAction`. [Source](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/blob/master/src/actions.js#L7-L14)

Comment: @AndreiGătej the error no longer shows, but now the console returns me the following error `Argument contains array with invalid element at index 0, it should be an action-creator instance from "typesafe-actions"`. Any idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to

> Argument contains array with invalid element at index 0, it should be an action-creator instance from "typesafe-actions"

It might throw that error because `ActionCreator` contains [ActionCreatorTypeMetadata](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions/blob/45bcfef89f98121a489848fca90a93b2666b71d2/src/type-helpers.ts#L113-L115) which requires `getType?: () => TType`:

```js
type TypeConstant = string;

export interface ActionCreatorTypeMetadata<TType extends TypeConstant> {
  getType?: () => TType;
}
```

[ActionCreator](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions/blob/master/src/is-action-of.ts#L8-L11)

```js
export type ActionCreator<T extends { type: string }> = ((
  ...args: any[]
) => T) &
  ActionCreatorTypeMetadata<T['type']>;
```

But, the `onLocationChanged` function implements only the first part of the intersection(a function that returns an object that has a property `type`).

```js
export const LOCATION_CHANGE = '@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE'

export const onLocationChanged = (location, action, isFirstRendering = false) => ({
  type: LOCATION_CHANGE,
  payload: {
    location,
    action,
    isFirstRendering,
  }
})
```

The function must also contain a property `getType`:

```js
onLocationChanged.getType = () => `YOUR_TYPE`.
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCBjGBLCA7AYSmAEMZoAeAFTlBmDwBMBnOAbwWWAC45mYo2PAHM4AXwB8cALxwAFHIBQcOADp1JKMOa8SeRAG0AuooCUMqVXMAyZeiy5CxMtCpcAssBglGZEtQMAciQUQKMJAG5FRRDUNxQCfH49eFl+QREoxVBIWDgheigAMxIMVEwcfCJScih44E9vX29qetoQeiZWesS8ZLwYKTY7YS96gH5eOXNpS3qosWiMJPgiiAheCsdqlygKDljedKFRSRl5Gak5YZUVQ7hAtAIqAEkAeQA5AH0qAE0ABQAooEADSKMSmaJrCCqUYwNqyaYWB5PV6fH4A4FRIA)

---

For those who are using `typesafe-actions`, you will need to register the `LOCATION_CHANGE` action,

```
import { LOCATION_CHANGE, RouterActionType } from 'connected-react-router';
import { Location } from 'history';
import { createAction } from 'typesafe-actions';

namespace RouterActions {

  export const onLocationChanged = createAction(
    LOCATION_CHANGE,
    (action) => (location: Location, routerAction: RouterActionType, isFirstRendering?: boolean) => action({
      location,
      action: routerAction,
      isFirstRendering,
    }),
  );
}

export default RouterActions;
```

And on your epics, you can simply listen to the `LOCATION_CHANGE` action,

```
const locationEpic: Epic = (action$) => action$.pipe(
  filter(isActionOf(RouterActions.onLocationChanged)),
  switchMap((epic) => {
    // do the rest
  }),

);
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help! The fix would be to create a typesafe action that mirrors LOCATION_CHANGE, such that it will be identified as a valid action.

Comment: Glad it helped! It was an interesting problem!:)

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for helping me out a few months ago! I think I have found an alternative solution. You might want to refer to it if you ever face this issue :)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to Andrei's excellent answer, I would like to propose an alternative solution to my question.

The problem with explicitly defining a 'fake' action to mirror the History action methods from [connected-react-router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-to-navigate-with-redux-action) (such as `push`, `replace`, `onLocationChanged`) is that, it will case further downstream issues when you need to call/listen to the action on your epics (such as [redux-observables](https://redux-observable.js.org/)).

Therefore, a better way of handling this problem would be to add the type for the History action methods on your main RootAction. For instance, if you wish to add the `replace` action as part of your Redux `RootAction`,

```
import { CallHistoryMethodAction, connectRouter, RouterState } from 'connected-react-router';
import { LocationState, Path } from 'history';

const actions = {
  userActions,
  settingsActions
};

type Replace = (path: Path, state?: LocationState) => CallHistoryMethodAction<[Path, LocationState?]>;

interface RouteActions {
  replace: Replace;
}

export type RootAction = ActionType<typeof actions> | ActionType<RouteActions>;

export interface RootState {
  router: RouterState;
  user: UserState;
  settings: SettingsState;
}
```

This will prevent `TypeScript`/`typesafe-actions` from flagging the error that your history actions are not defined.